# How do I activate this wheel with the green box?

Tags: momodora-reverie-under-moonlight

I came across a wheel above a small 1 tile gap in the wall blocked by a door. Presumably the wheel would open the door. When I inspect the wheel it shows an icon of a green box. Do I need to find this green box to activate the wheel? If so, where can I find it?

[image: Wheel with green box]

[image: Map location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This green box item is called the Sealed Wind, found at the top of the Royal Pinacotheca. Once you unlocked it, you can use its active effect to activate the windmill you're facing.

[image]